.NET MAUI Real-Time Detect Current CultureInfo Changed?
I followed the tutorial in this youtube Video by Geralt about Multilingual on .NET MAUI, very good and very detailed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cf4sXULR7os
After many times I Googled the results from StackOverFlow, I could not find the answer for myself.
I have a MVVM class like this:
namespace MyNameProject.Models
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Name))]
    public partial class ResourceModels : ObservableObject, IMarkupExtension<BindingBase>
    {
        private ResourceModels() => Language.Culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        private static ResourceModels obj;
        internal static ResourceModels Obj { get { if (obj == null) obj = new(); return obj; } set => obj = value; }
        public object this[string resourceKey]
        => Language.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceKey, Language.Culture) ?? Array.Empty<byte>();
        public void setCulture(CultureInfo culture) => Language.Culture = culture;
    }
}

To be able to detect CultureInfo change. On each XAML Page, I have to write and call the event like this:
In PAGE Contructor i write:
ResourceModels.Obj.PropertyChanged += Obj_PropertyChanged;

And this method for that:
private void Obj_PropertyChanged(object? sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ResourceModels.Obj.setCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}

It is really troublesome when working with a project with many PAGE, and I am not working on only 1 project.., please everyone show me how to do this Global Real-Time once and for all. And this will live forever from the moment I open the application until I exit the application.

not very sure what you intended but i guess you may take a look at singelton with dependency injection

Adding to @Cfun, create a MAUI class library, with Base View Model, shared services or shared functions

Could you please share more relevant code to help us reproduce the question? Do you use data binding to update the UI?

To detect/trigger a change to CultureInfo.CurrentValue one should call CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData(). Typically, I define a LocalizationManager class to do this and register it as a singleton, e.g.
public partial class LocalizationManager : ObservableObject
{
    public CultureInfo CurrentCulture => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    public CultureInfo CurrentUICulture => CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

    public void Update()
    {
        string _name = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData(); // trigger update
        if (_name != CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentCulture));
            // optionally update UI culture for localized text from resources
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentUICulture));
        }
    }
}

Then, with the above code, it is left up to your discretion as to how often you call LocalizationManger.Update(). A couple of options are, (1) you can poll it regularly, (2) you can poll it when your app loses, and reacquires active focus. The latter makes use of the fact that most users will update their language settings in the OS, and, typically, leave and enter the app.
You need to have an understanding that CultureInfo.CurrentCulture and CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture are for different use cases:

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture - typically is reserved for currency, numbers, and decimal and thousand's separators
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture - typically reserved for localized text (e.g. "Hello World" in English, French, ...)

When an app is running, typically, changes at the OS level will only manifest in changes in the former, i.e. CultureInfo.CurrentCulture. Your app has to decide when to propagate those changes to CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.
